# Jquery Remove elements including parent element

Tags: jquery, html

I want to remove elements from my page. I want to remove all .Panel elements which do not also have the .SelectedPanel class.

```
$('.Panel :not(.SelectedPanel)').remove();
```

I have tried the above, which works, but leaves the parent col divs - I want to remove these as well. So with the markup below, I want the middle column to be removed.

```
<div class='row'>                
    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-1'>
        <div class='Panel SelectedPanel'>
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-1'>
        <div class='Panel'>
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-1'>
        <div class='Panel SelectedPanel'>
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try $('.Panel :not(.SelectedPanel)').parent().remove();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reference the parent, like so. It will remove the entire DOM elements, including their children.

```
$('.Panel:not(.SelectedPanel)').parent().remove();
```